# format string date to format with am pm

Tags: javascript, date

I've implemented format function to convert input hours `9a-7p` to `9:00am - 7:00pm` or `9:30a-7p` to `9:30am to 7:30pm`.

the inputs looks like `{sun: 9a-7p, mon: 8:30a - 7p}`

Is there more generic way how to handle it this case, cuz this one does not cover `pm - am` or `am - am` or `pm - pm`

```
const formattedHours = (days: {[day: string]: string}) => {
  return Object.keys(days).map((day) => {
    const [openHours, closedHours] = days[day].replaceAll('a', '').replaceAll('p', '').split('-');

    const [openHour, openMinute = '00'] = openHours.split(':');
    const [closedHour, closedMinute = '00'] = closedHours.split(':');

    return `${openHour}:${openMinute}am - ${closedHour}:${closedMinute}pm`;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of going about it. By checking for the presence of 'a' or 'p' we can store the meridian and insert it after scrubbing the element of text, extra spaces and making sure it has minutes included. I used `Object.entries` since it allows me to iterate the object and modify the value in question in the same loop. I surround the whole thing with `Object.fromEntries` to convert it back into an object.

```js
let data = {
  sun: "9a-7p",
  mon: "8:30a - 7p",
  tues: "9pm - 11pm",
  weds: "7am - 11:45 am",
  thurs: "11a-12:00pm"
};

const formattedHours = days => {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(days).map((day) => {
    day[1] = day[1].split("-").map(t => {
      let merid = t.includes('a') ? 'am' : 'pm';
      t = t.replaceAll(/[a-zA-Z]/g, '').trim()
      if (!t.includes(':')) t = `${t}:00`;
      t += merid
      return t
    }).join("-");
    return day
  }));
};

let newdata = formattedHours(data);
console.log(newdata)
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to go about it, but fundamentally it's about converting the time to a different format. The following also pads the hour with spaces to help with alignment, missing minutes are treated as "0" and single digit minutes are padded with a leading zero.

```js
let fixTime = time => {
  let range = time.split(/\s*-\s*/).map(time => {
    let [h,m] = time.match(/\d+/g);
    return `${h.padStart(2, ' ')}:${(m || '0').padStart(2, '0')}${/a/.test(time)? 'am' : 'pm'}`;
  });
  return range.join(' to ');
};

let data = {
  sun: '9a-7p',
  mon: '8:30a - 7p',
  tue: '10:31a -1:5p',
  wed: '1:31p-11:5p',
};


let result = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, day) => {
  acc[day] = fixTime(data[day]);
  return acc;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```